# How to send packets during receive IRQ of network driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

For a research project, I am currently modifying a linux driver. I am fairly new to this topic, so I'm not sure if there's an obvious mistake I'm making here.

My goal is to catch incoming ICMP packets during the drivers IRQ and send a reply back to the sender immediately. For now, it doesn't matter, if checksums or anything are correct, I just want to send something back as fast as possible. In order to do that I run the following code during the IRQ:

```
data = skb-> data;

/* we received an ICMP request. Send custom reply. */
if(data[9] == 1){// && data[20] == 8){
   unsigned long start = jiffies;
   unsigned long end;
   u8 * newdata;
   u16 ippacketLength;
   sk_quickreply = dev_alloc_skb(128);

   struct ethhdr *  mac_skb_quick;
   struct iphdr * iph_skb_quick;
   struct ethhdr *  mac_skb = eth_hdr(skb);

   struct iphdr * iph_skb = data;

   quicktransmit = 1;


   /* Put icmp packet */
   skb_push(sk_quickreply, 26);

   /* Put IP header */
   skb_push(sk_quickreply, sizeof(struct iphdr));
   skb_reset_network_header(sk_quickreply);
   iph_skb_quick = ip_hdr(sk_quickreply);
   iph_skb_quick->version = 4;
   iph_skb_quick->ihl = 5;
   iph_skb_quick->ttl = 64;
   iph_skb_quick->daddr = iph_skb->saddr;
   iph_skb_quick->saddr = iph_skb->daddr;
   iph_skb_quick->protocol = 1; //ICMP
   ip_send_check(iph_skb_quick);


   /* Put MAC header */
   eth_header(sk_quickreply, dev, ETH_P_802_3, mac_skb->h_source, mac_skb->h_dest, 14);
   skb_reset_mac_header(sk_quickreply);
   mac_skb_quick = eth_hdr(sk_quickreply);

   rtl8168_mystart_xmit(sk_quickreply,dev);
}
```

Where rtl8168_mystart_xmit is the hard_start_xmit function the driver originally provided, except I removed spinlocks:

```
static int rtl8168_mystart_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb,
               struct net_device *dev)
{

    struct rtl8168_private *tp = netdev_priv(dev);
    unsigned int frags, entry;
    struct TxDesc *txd;
    void __iomem *ioaddr = tp->mmio_addr;
    dma_addr_t mapping;
    u32 len;
    u32 opts1;
    u32 opts2;
    int ret = NETDEV_TX_OK;
    unsigned long flags, large_send;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Starting transmission of fast reply.\n");



    if (unlikely(TX_BUFFS_AVAIL(tp) < skb_shinfo(skb)->nr_frags)) {
            if (netif_msg_drv(tp)) {
                    printk(KERN_ERR
                           "%s: BUG! Tx Ring full when queue awake!\n",
                           dev->name);
            }
            goto err_stop;
    }

    entry = tp->cur_tx % NUM_TX_DESC;
    txd = tp->TxDescArray + entry;



    if (unlikely(le32_to_cpu(txd->opts1) & DescOwn))
            goto err_stop;

    opts1 = DescOwn;
    opts2 = rtl8168_tx_vlan_tag(tp, skb);

      large_send = 0;
    if (dev->features & NETIF_F_TSO) {

            u32 mss = skb_shinfo(skb)->gso_size;

            printk(KERN_INFO "Large send.\n");

            /* TCP Segmentation Offload (or TCP Large Send) */
            if (mss) {
                    if ((tp->mcfg == CFG_METHOD_1) ||
                        (tp->mcfg == CFG_METHOD_2) ||
                        (tp->mcfg == CFG_METHOD_3)) {
                            opts1 |= LargeSend | ((mss & MSSMask) << 16);
                    } else if ((tp->mcfg == CFG_METHOD_11) ||
                               (tp->mcfg == CFG_METHOD_12) ||
                               (tp->mcfg == CFG_METHOD_13)) {
                            opts2 |= LargeSend_DP | ((mss & MSSMask) << 18);
                    } else {
                            opts1 |= LargeSend;
                            opts2 |= (mss & MSSMask) << 18;
                    }
                    large_send = 1;
            }
    }



    if (large_send == 0) {
         printk(KERN_INFO "No large send.\n");
            if (dev->features & NETIF_F_IP_CSUM) {
                    if ((tp->mcfg == CFG_METHOD_1) || (tp->mcfg == CFG_METHOD_2) || (tp->mcfg == CFG_METHOD_3))
                            opts1 |= rtl8168_tx_csum(skb, dev);
                    else
                            opts2 |= rtl8168_tx_csum(skb, dev);
            }
    }



    frags = rtl8168_xmit_frags(tp, skb, opts1, opts2);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Frags: %u\n", frags);
    if (frags) {
            len = skb_headlen(skb);
            opts1 |= FirstFrag;
    } else {
            len = skb->len;

            tp->tx_skb[entry].skb = skb;

            if (tp->UseSwPaddingShortPkt && len < 60) {
                printk(KERN_INFO "Packet uses padding\n");
                    rtl8168_sw_padding_short_pkt(tp, skb, opts1, opts2);
                    opts1 |= FirstFrag;
                    frags++;
            } else {
                printk(KERN_INFO "Packet doesn't use padding\n");
                //This code means, the fragment is the first and the last fragment to be send
                    opts1 |= FirstFrag | LastFrag;
            }
    }


    printk(KERN_INFO "Length: %u\n", len);
    opts1 |= len | (RingEnd * !((entry + 1) % NUM_TX_DESC));
    mapping = pci_map_single(tp->pci_dev, skb->data, len, PCI_DMA_TODEVICE);
    tp->tx_skb[entry].len = len;
    txd->addr = cpu_to_le64(mapping);
    txd->opts2 = cpu_to_le32(opts2);
    txd->opts1 = cpu_to_le32(opts1&~DescOwn);
    wmb();
    txd->opts1 = cpu_to_le32(opts1);

    dev->trans_start = jiffies;

    tp->cur_tx += frags + 1;

    wmb();



    RTL_W8(TxPoll, HPQ);    /* set polling bit */






out:
    return ret;
err_stop:
    printk(KERN_INFO "Problem: Jumped to err_stop\n");
    //netif_stop_queue(dev);
    //ret = NETDEV_TX_BUSY;
    //RTLDEV->stats.tx_dropped++;

    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&tp->lock, flags);
    goto out;
}
```

I'm sending ping requests from a second computer who's nic I've set to promiscuous mode. It seems like the reply never gets sent in the first place. What am I doing wrong or is such a transmission during the IRQ even possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this. You should be processing the IRQ as fast as possible, and that doesn't include engaging in other netwrok activities.

Comment: Thanks ejp for your comment. I'm aware that the irq might become unacceptably long. I'm trying to minimize the impact the schedule has on the package processing and this is one naive approach. My goal is just to figure out if this basically works.